# Add spaces before text you Entered in EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout

when begin to write in EditText the cursor of writing still in the  first as photo

[image]

i want to add spaces before writing as this

[image]

i am trying to make EditText in another app and working well and there is a space automatically before cursor

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ebebeb" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ebebeb"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dip" >

        <!-- View Title Label -->
        <!-- Address line Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:text="@string/address_line"
            android:textColor="#359c5e"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <!-- Address Line TextField -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addressline"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="2dip" />

        <!-- City Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:text="@string/city"
            android:textColor="#359c5e"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <!-- City TextField -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="2dip" />

        <!-- State Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:text="@string/state"
            android:textColor="#359c5e"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <!-- state TextField -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/state"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="2dip" />

        <!-- Postal code Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:text="@string/postal_code"
            android:textColor="#359c5e"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <!-- postal code TextField -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/postalcode"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="2dip" />

        <!-- Country  Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:text="@string/country"
            android:textColor="#359c5e"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <!-- Country TextField -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/country"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="2dip" />

        <!-- Additional instructions  Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:text="@string/additional_instructions"
            android:textColor="#359c5e"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <!-- Country TextField -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/additional"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:hint="@string/info"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What about adding `android:paddingLeft="16dip"` to your EditTexts?

Comment: @Vyger yes it woks but 16dp is very large for that..

Comment: thanks sir , worked well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with the `android:padding` attribute.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

padding is a attribute in android,which helps you to achieve this.

```
android:padding="space in dp" // how much space you want to before your text

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/addressline"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />
```